# I had this exercise when I wanted to calculate the sum of the following series

Tags: c++

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljdEn.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int factorial(int x){
int fact=1;
if (x==1){
return 1;
}
else{
    fact=x*factorial(x-1);
}
return fact;
}

int main()
{
double sum1=0;
double sum2=0;
for (int i=1;i<100;i=i+2){

sum1=sum1+1/factorial(i);
}
 for (int j=2;j<101;j=j+2){
        sum2=sum2-1/factorial(j);
    }
    double sum;
    sum=sum1+sum2;
    cout<<sum<<endl;

}
```

What did I do wrong here? Codeblocks keeps giving me an error while running.. and what are better alternatives for this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the error you get?  Also include you question as text.

Comment: `1/factorial(i)` will be 0 when `i>1` and overflow is not caused. Did you mean `1.0/factorial(i)`?

Comment: `100!` is approximately 9.3e+157. there is absolutely **NO** way for that to fit into an integer.

Comment: @MarcB The last term is not `1/100!` but `1/1000!` for some reason.

Comment: Factorial of `100` is a damn large number. It will overflow `int` many times. Sometimes it might overflow and become zero. And division by zero is bad..

Comment: @MarcB I think the 1000! was meant to be a 100 as the question right before it was just till 100 , and Yea once I used double in my function It worked thanks guys ^^

Comment: irrelevant. an int is a 16bit value. you didn't make it unsigned, so the largest int you can represent is 32767, which means 7! (5040) is the LARGEST factorial you'll ever be able to successfully calculate with this code. 8!  = 40320 and overflows your int.

Comment: @MarcB An int can be bigger than 16 bits.  On many systems it is 32 bits.  Still doesn't help though.

Comment: indeed. just makes the max fact a smidge bigger, but not by much. 11! or so.

Comment: @MarcB I am not used to this sort of datatypes. atleast, I don't give them much attention as my first programming language was Matlab. thanks for helping me understand that tho

Comment: You might want to apply some math on the expression first.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`sum=0`. The result you are looking for is `sum = sum1 + sum2 = 0`.

The code had to be rewritten. However if you use 64 bits then you can 
fit more but as i am using 32 bits, i could only get `i` to 17 before
`sum1` and `sum2` overflowed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


long factorial(long x){
    if (x == 1) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return x*factorial(x-1);  
    }
}


int main(){
    cout<<"\n";

    int n = 15;
    int i=0;
    double sum = 0;
    double sum1=0;
    double sum2=0;

    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum1 += 1.0/factorial(i); 
        cout<<" factorial("<<i<<") = "<<factorial(i)<<" , 1/factorial("<<i<<") = "<<sum1<<" \n";
    }

    cout<<"\nSum1 = "<<sum1<<"\n\n";

    for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        sum2 -= 1.0/factorial(i); 
        cout<<" factorial("<<i<<") = "<<factorial(i)<<" , 1/factorial("<<i<<") = "<<sum2<<" \n";
    }

    cout<<"\nsum2 = "<<sum2<<"\n\n";

    sum=sum1+sum2;
    cout<<"Sum1+sum2 = "<<sum<<endl;

cout<<"\n";
return 0;

}
```